# Can't create columnstore index

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, t-sql

When I try to create a columnstore index using the following syntax

```
create nonclustered columnstore index indx1 on table1 (row1, row2)
```

I get an error message on the 'columnstore' keyword saying `incorrect syntax near columnstore.  Expecting INDEX`, and another error message on the 'row1' saying `incorrect syntax, expecting "(", or SELECT`

I am in SQL server 2012.  I have tried this on temp tables and permanent tables, and still get these errors.  What is going wrong?

thanks

Comment: Post a complete, executable T-SQL script demonstrating the issue.

Comment: what is the compatibility level of your database?, are `row1, row2` your column names?

Comment: @Lamak yes those are the column names.  The compatability level is 100, so SQL 2008... maybe that is the problem.  My SSMS is 2012 though, so maybe the syntax is registering but it isn't working when compiled...

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter if your version of SQL Server **Management** Studio is 2014 if the database has compatibility level 100, then that database only has the features of SQL Server 2008, hence no columnstore indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQL 2008

This server version does not support columnstore indexes. The SQL that you write runs on the server. All the client does is transmit the SQL string over the network. You could send command with telnet if you wanted to.

Maybe this is your misunderstanding: In many languages code is compiled into some build output like a binary that can run anywhere. With SQL, the text is sent to the server and runs there.